# How to remove an element from a list in R while maintaining the original list print formatting?

Tags: r, list, formatting, subset

I've searched far and wide on Stack Overflow and online generally on how to remove specific elements from a list and I've partly figured out how to do this. However, when I remove an element from this example list, I lose the original nice formatting of the list. Let me explain in the image that follows. How do I remove the "Call" element and the text that follows it ("*survdiff(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)*"), while retaining the original formatting?

Example code is posted at the bottom.

[image]

Example code:

```
library(survival)
library(survmine)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
surv_diff <- survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
surv_diff

str(surv_diff)

test <- surv_diff[-7] # trying to remove the "Call" element and all its text
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the call element from the object? Are you just trying to change how the object prints? It would be better/safer to make a customized print function for that object instead. It’s generally not a good idea to manipulate the intervals of an object.

Comment: Hi Mr. Flick, I'm only changing how it prints. I'm trying to "pretty it up" for rendering in Shiny. Nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove that element, you remove the class attribute.  You can place it back like this:

```
class(test) <- "survdiff"
```

Comment: In my Shiny app, this solution works best.  The surv_diff object is wrapped in `reactive(...)`, and I find objects defined in a reactive are much easier to work with using pipe operators. To get this to work in a Shiny reactive the code is `surv_diff()[-length(surv_diff())] %>% "class<-"("survdiff")`

Answer (score 1):

I ran your example code and it gives me a list of 6 items (no pvalue). So in my case I am working on the 6th element - you might need to work on the 7th.

```
# remove sixth list item (keeping the class attribute)
surv_diff[6] <- NULL

# look at the resulting list 
str(surv_diff)
List of 5
 $ n    : 'table' int [1:2(1d)] 138 90
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ groups: chr [1:2] "sex=1" "sex=2"
 $ obs  : num [1:2] 112 53
 $ exp  : num [1:2] 91.6 73.4
 $ var  : num [1:2, 1:2] 40.4 -40.4 -40.4 40.4
 $ chisq: num 10.3
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "survdiff"

 # print
 surv_diff
        N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
 sex=1 138      112     91.6      4.55      10.3
 sex=2  90       53     73.4      5.68      10.3

  Chisq= 10.3  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.001
```

Please bear in mind that removing parts from object probably will implicate some type of mal behaviour when further processing it.